# Converting jQuery parallax function to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

This is a working parallax function that works by adding ' data-type="parallax" ' and ' data-speed="5" ' data attributes to the HTML element you wish to parallax.

However, it is the only jQuery I am using on my site. I was hoping to convert it to vanilla js to save some bundle size.

All of my attempt have failed. Any help is appricated!

```
$(() => {
  // Cache the Window object
  const $window = $(window);

  $('[data-type="parallax"]').each(function() {
    const paraElm = $(this); // assigning the object
    $window.scroll(() => {
      // Scroll the background at var speed
      // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!
      const yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / paraElm.data('speed'));

      // Put together our final background position
      const coords = `50% ${yPos}px`;

      // Move the background
      paraElm.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please create a sample fiddle on codepen or jsfidde in order to work from there?

Comment: Considering all the cross-browser issues jQuery fixes, the question is too broad. Please narrow down the question, and your attempt would be also wellcome ...

Comment: I'd suggest you make it without JS. Pure CSS solution saves the size and improves performance.

Comment: If you want to reimplement it, start your conversion and post a detailed question once you're stuck, as this is too broad. If you just want to replace it with another 3rd party script just look for a vanillajs script (1st hit on google is this one https://github.com/dixonandmoe/rellax)

Comment: Check this site: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/